# How can I place two views depending on their width?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-view, android-constraintlayout

In our project we have such a case: we have two textviews (let's say, `@id/text_view_1` and `@id/text_view_2`). We should place them horizontally (`@id/text_view_1` and then `@id/text_view_2`) if their width combined is less than the width of their parent or vertically (`text_view_2` above `text_view_1`) if they are too wide.
Right now the best solution I've come up with looks something like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/parent"
    android:layout_width="match_parent" 
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text_view_above_2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text_view_1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/text_view_2_right"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/text_view_2_right"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text_view_right_2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/text_view_2_above"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/text_view_1" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Here is the logic of toggling visibility of `text_view`s

```
private void toggleVisibility() {
    TextView textView1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text_view_1);
    TextView textViewAbove2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text_view_above_2);
    TextView textViewRight2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text_view_right_2);

    textView1.measure(0, 0);
    textViewAbove2.measure(0, 0);
    textViewRight2.measure(0, 0);

    View parent = findViewById(R.id.parent);
    parent.measure(0, 0);

    if (textView1.getMeasuredWidth() + textViewRight2.getMeasuredWidth() < parent.getMeasuredWidth()) {
        textViewAbove2.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        textViewRight2.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    } else {
        textViewRight2.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        textViewAbove2.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }
}
```

Is there a solution more "beautiful" and shorter than the one I've described? I guess there is a way to do it with `ConstraintLayout` instead of `RelativeLayout` but I'm not sure.

**EDIT 1:** probably I have to provide the result I want to see. Here is what an activity supposed to look like if [both views are short:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W3fRz.png)

And here is what it should look like if [views are too long:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DqQ4f.png)

Comment: what is your desired output can u share any image of required output

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take a look at [`FlexboxLayout`](https://github.com/google/flexbox-layout).

Here is a solution using `FlexboxLayout`:

```
<com.google.android.flexbox.FlexboxLayout
    android:id="@+id/parent"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:flexWrap="wrap">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="16dp"
        android:text="This is a short string." />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="16dp"
        android:text="This is another short string." />

</com.google.android.flexbox.FlexboxLayout>
```

[image]

Using the same XML with a longer string for the first text view yields the following:

[image]

Comment: Thank you! That helped a lot!

Comment: Cool, I always thought what would be the best way to build tags/keywords list like https://www.dropbox.com/s/gzyactsjkx8axac/30_04.png?dl=0. And seems like FlexboxLayout is something works best for that case.

Comment: By the way, they even have a FlexboxLayoutManager for a RecyclerView so that might be even more useful for the case you have described.

Answer (score 0):

Solution:If you want to set `TextView` as per their width requirements then you will simply use `LinearLayout` as parent with width wrap_content and for both child TextViews also give width 'wrap_content'

Answer (score 0):

try using wrap_content and put these child text views inside a parent LinearLayout , give wrap_content as width for both of the child textviews. It will place according to the content in those textviews.

If You want to put Views Horizontally --

```
 <LinearLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/parent"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text_view1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        />

     <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text_view2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        />

</LinearLayout>
```

If You want to put Views Vertically --

```
<LinearLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/parent"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text_view1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        />

     <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text_view2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Unfortunately I need something different. I need these view to be placed vertically if they are too wide and you propose a solution which places views always horizontally.

Comment: I updated my answer , Now you can see for both Horizontal and Vertical orientations

Answer (score -1):

Try using percentagelayout . This might help. For more details provide desired output.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Provided desired output. Aren't layouts based on using percent supposed to be deprecated at least since API v26?

Comment: You can use Constraint layout it has more flexibility.